# MySql self join unexpected result inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I am learning about SQL joins from this tutorial: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-a-self-join/

The table they are using is:

```
+---------------+-------------------+
| employee_name | employee_location |
+---------------+-------------------+
| Joe           | New York          |
| Sunil         | India             |
| Alex          | Russia            |
| Albert        | Canada            |
| Jack          | New York          |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

I decided to experiment with the queries by leaving out certain parts like this:

```
select * from
employee t1, employee t2
where t1.employee_location = t2.employee_location
```

This query seemed pretty straightforward. "Match up people with the same location. I thought ok, the result will be this:

```
+---------------+-------------------++---------------+-------------------+
| employee_name | employee_location || employee_name | employee_location |
+---------------+-------------------++---------------+-------------------+
| Joe           | New York          || Joe           | New York          |
| Sunil         | India             || Sunil         | India             |
| Alex          | Russia            || Alex          | Russia            |
| Albert        | Canada            || Albert        | Canada            |
| Jack          | New York          || Jack          | New York          |
+---------------+-------------------++---------------+-------------------+
```

But instead of the above I got this:

```
+---------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
| employee_name | employee_location | employee_name | employee_location |
+---------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
| Joe           | New York          | Joe           | New York          |
| Jack          | New York          | Joe           | New York          |
| Sunil         | India             | Sunil         | India             |
| Alex          | Russia            | Alex          | Russia            |
| Albert        | Canada            | Albert        | Canada            |
| Joe           | New York          | Jack          | New York          |
| Jack          | New York          | Jack          | New York          |
+---------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

It works fine for Sunil, Alex and Albert. The combinations of Joe and Jack I do not understand. Can someone explain in detail how this works aside from the solution? I would like to understand the logic behind this result.

Comment: If you are learning SQL from a site that uses commas in the `from` clause, then find another resource to learn SQL.  You don't want to learn the version of the language that was prevalent 25 years ago, before cell phone where used, tablets were invented, and cloud computing didn't exist.

Comment: The almost exact same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639221/self-join-returning-more-rows-than-expected) was asked a few hours ago and got a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31639286/1175077) that should explain it too you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the tip. And explanation to my problem would help me more though.

Comment: @jpw thanks for pointing that out. Still scratching my head though.

Comment: any takers? still do not understand from looking at the referred answer. I am new and it would help a lot.

Comment: In a nutshell, and as explained in the duplicate question/answer, this says "For every record in T1, find all matches in T2" (the fact that T1 and T2 are the same table doesn't really matter.) So for Joe|New York it matches Joe|New York and Jack|New York. Then for Jack|New York it matches Joe|New York and Jack|New York. This is because the |New York is all it's looking at, and both records have that location.

Comment: Is there like a right to left comparison/direction or something. It kind of seems like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the New York rows from `t1` matches against two rows in `t2` since all you're requiring is that the cities be the same. So you get 2 x 2 total matches (pairs) for New York. If you added a third New York then you'd get 9 rows.

To see the behavior you're expecting try adding `and t1.employee_name = t2.employee.name`. You can't uniquely identify *all* people by location alone even though with *most* of them you can and so your result appears to almost work.

Comment: Ok,ok i can see t1.joe matching t2.joe and t2.jack then t1.jack matching t2.joe and t2.jack. what throws me off is the ordering in t1 having of joe, jack ... joe jack

Comment: There's no significance or meaning at all in the ordering. In SQL the only way to guarantee a sort is to use `order by` and without that you should always ignore the way results come back.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in within the "where" statement:
where t1.employee_location = t2.employee_location
Joe and Jack both match New York so are multiplied.
You can see this better by adding another New York entry and re-running. You will get 9 New York results.
To get what you expected you would need to add "and where t1.employee_name = t2.employee_name.